# Are python venvs portable?

Tags: python, virtualenv, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I am developing a game that I want to be able to easily distribute.
I am trying many ways of compiling it, and most of them fail all the time.
I came across the idea of creating a virtualenv for the game, since it has its own python interpreter, and then make it portable.

If I did that, would the game be executable on a PC that does not have python installed? If so, would it then be cross-compatible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+portable

Comment: No, Python virtual environments are not portable. It's a development tool but not a distribution/deployment tool.